# Write into .bat file with java

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to create my own RCP application but I have a problem: I want to open a batch script with java code and write some arguments to it

Any Help please thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "open a script bat with java code and write some argument"?

Comment: write in my .bat with java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch file (with suffix`.bat`) is basically a simple text file.

To write text to a file use a `FileWriter`, e.g.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("my.bat");
writer.write("REM a batch file");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the batch file with ProcessBuilder and you can pass the argument seperated with spaces to the batch file.

ProcessBuilder procbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(BatchFilePath With Seperated Arguments)